# How do you add time together?

Tags: c, function, int

I'm trying to convert time from UTC time/date to what time it would be in Christchurch New Zealand. PS, I am a beginner coder.

I can easily identify the timezone offset and take into consideration daylight savings. My question is, how can I add UTC and the offset time (+1200)

```
int timeConverted (int utcTime, int timezoneOffset) {

    int answer = 0;
    int totalTime = utctime + timezoneOffset;

    int timeAdded = totalTime;

    if (timeAdded > 2359) {
        answer = timeAdded - 2400;
    }

    return answer;
```

When I do this I get some funny looking answers. This is for Adelaide, Australia time

Input is 1659
Out is 189 (the answer should be 229)

I can only use if statements (no arrays or anything like that)

Comment: it's difficult to answer your question with this piece of code, can you edit the code to show more ?

Comment: 859 + 1200 = 2059 so your problem is somewhere else.

Comment: @ThiruShetty Yea, I fixed that now. Though still a problem here. Edited my first post

Comment: @immibis Yep, fixed it now, but edit my first post, because I still have issues

Comment: Have you tried doing the math on paper to see where the problem is?

Comment: @immibis Yes I have, I can see the problem is it counts over 60. But I don’t know how I can code (if th last 2 digits are over 60, add 100)

Comment: How about `if (yournumber % 100 >= 60)` ?

Comment: With a UTC time of `1659` and TZ offset `+/-1200` the result is `459` -- how are you arriving at `229`??

Comment: `189` is `1` hour, `89` minutes, which is conventionally written as `229` or `2` hours `29` minutes.  You've forgotten that you're using base 100 numbers to represent base 60 values.  Fixing it is not entirely trivial; you have to take the value of the time modulo 100, and if the result is bigger than 59, subtract 60 from it and carry 1 to the hundreds (adding an hour).  It would be simpler if you used either separate hours and minutes or computed the result as decimal minutes and then fixed the presentation on output.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, and you want to take the UTC time and timezone offset and then compute local time (for Adelaide, Australia with `+930` timezone offset), then you have 3 cases to handle:

1. are the resulting minutes greater than `59`? (if so add `40`)
2. is the resulting answer greater than `2359`? (if so subtract `2400`)
3. is the resulting answer less than `0` (if so add `2400`)

You can handle that in a fairly simple manner:

```
int timeConverted (int utcTime, int timezoneOffset) {

    int answer = utcTime + timezoneOffset,
        utcmin = utcTime % 100,         /* consider minutes */
        offmin = timezoneOffset % 100;  /* from each time */

    if (utcmin + offmin > 59)   /* handle minutes 60-99 */
        answer += 40;

    if (answer > 2359)          /* answer greater than 2359 */
        answer -= 2400;

    if (answer < 0)             /* answer less than 0 */
        answer += 2400;

    return answer;
}
```

Putting it altogether in a simple example that takes `utcTime` as the first argument to the program (`1659` default) and takes `timezoneOffset` as the second argument (`1200` default), you could do something like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int timeConverted (int utcTime, int timezoneOffset) {

    int answer = utcTime + timezoneOffset,
        utcmin = utcTime % 100,         /* consider minutes */
        offmin = timezoneOffset % 100;  /* from each time */

    if (utcmin + offmin > 59)   /* handle minutes 60-99 */
        answer += 40;

    if (answer > 2359)          /* answer greater than 2359 */
        answer -= 2400;

    if (answer < 0)             /* answer less than 0 */
        answer += 2400;

    return answer;
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    int utc = argc > 1 ? strtol (argv[1], NULL, 0) : 1659,
        tzo = argc > 2 ? strtol (argv[2], NULL, 0) : 1200;

    printf ("utcTime : %d\noffset  : %d\nlocal   : %d\n",
            utc, tzo, timeConverted (utc, tzo));
}
```

(**note:** to set `timezoneOffset` both arguments are required)

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/tzoffset 1659 930
utcTime : 1659
offset  : 930
local   : 229
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions. (also let me know if I misunderstood your question)

Yes, now `2359 845` works correctly, e.g.

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/tzoffset 2359 845
utcTime : 2359
offset  : 845
local   : 844
```

Comment: You want to add `100` and subtract `60` so the *Net* is adding `40`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Very helpful and yea, you understood my question. However, it does work when the time is 2359. For example, an offset of 845, and a UTC time of 2359. Also I haven’t learnt arguments. I am doing everything with if statements

Comment: Ah -- your are right.. Let me fix that and I'll update.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin So what does offMin mean?

Comment: That's just the `minutes` part of `timezoneOffset`, and `utcmin` is just the minutes part of `utcTime`. You care about whether the combination will exceed `59` not whether the final result of adding them together exceeds `59` (that's where my original fell short, `59 + 45 = 04`, the important part is `59 + 45 > 59`, not `4 > 59`)

Comment: so offMin is the amount of minutes in the Timezone

Comment: Yes and No, it just the minutes (e.g. `845 % 100 = 45` and `2359 % 100 = 59`). It's just a mathematical way of picking off the minutes with `mod`. (well YES, it is the remainder, but it is the `mod` -- I see what you are saying, I just want to make sure when we say remainder we are talking about the mathematical remainder of the division `845/100` which is `845 % 100`)

Comment: Also, don't be confused by `utc = argc > 1 ? strtol (argv[1], NULL, 0) : 1659` it is just a *ternary* operator `value = test ? if true val : if false val;` (it is a shorthand `if (test) true val; else false val;`) It is an easy way to check if `argc > 1` (meaning there is 1 argument on the command line) so  `? strtol (argv[1], NULL, 0)` convert it to a `long` and assign that to `utc`, but if `argc > 1` is failse, then use a default of `1659` and assign that to `utc`. The ternary can be used anywhere you need one of two values depending on some test `:)`